# Repair Bootcamp Windows 10 0xc0000225

Tags: windows-10, boot, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I'm usually running my Bootcamp partition in VMWare Fusion. When resuming from sleeping the computer told me it was restarted due to a problem. Now the Windows 10 partition doesn't boot, either in Bootcamp mode or in VMWare Fusion. The bluescreen error is 0xc0000225

I have run chkdsk c: /offlinescanandfix from a repair usb stick, but it didn't help. I have tried to set the Bootcamp partion active using Diskpart from the Windows repair usb stick, but it told me that the partition couldn't. Gpt? Don't remember.

I can access the Bootcamp partition from Finder in OSX.

My mac is a MacBook Pro Mid 2015 running Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I'm not sure but this link may help https://www.kapilarya.com/your-pc-needs-to-be-repaired-0xc0000225

Comment: See this article https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc0000225/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all available fixes, but in the end I had to reinstall. I couldn't either do a repair installation. I had to do a clean install. Despite, it moved all my old files to windows.old and my own folders in c:\ was still there.

This is the second or third time this happens. I'm going to put all important stuff in onedrive and use reinstall as first option.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, there's one way I've found to resolve this. If you have access to another computer, take out the affected computer's primary drive and find a way to mount it in the system (internally, externally, whatever). Then do the following:

1. Open command prompt as an administrator
2. Type in `diskpart`
3. Type in `list disk`. Find out which disk the affected drive is.
4. Type in `select disk #`, where # is the affected drive's number
5. Type in `list partition`, find the partition number of the system partition (it's usually 100MB, 200MB, or 300MB), then
6. Type in `select partition #`, where # is the system partition's number.
7. Type in `assign letter=z`, assuming you don't have a `Z:` drive.
8. Exit out of diskpart by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
   or typing `exit`
9. Type in

   ```
   BCDBoot [Drive letter of affected drive's Windows partition]:\Windows /S Z: /F UEFI
   ```

   So if the affected drive's Windows partition is, say, `G:\`,
   you would type in

   ```
   BCDBoot G:\Windows /S Z: /F UEFI
   ```

It works for me.